# Change of main font

Tags: bug, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Font bug: Main site font renders German closing quotation marks wrongly](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56/font-bug-main-site-font-renders-german-closing-quotation-marks-wrongly)

The main font used for this site – Tahoma – unfortunately has a problem with the closing quotation marks commonly used in German, U+201C and U+2018. That is, the glyphs are rendered inverted and thus imbalance the text:

[image: Tahoma]
versus
[image: Minion Pro]

The second text is rendered in Minion Pro; note the inverted closing quotation mark.

Not a big deal obviously, but kind of ugly (and unexpected).

[Reference [in German]](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anf%C3%BChrungszeichen#Probleme_und_h.C3.A4ufige_Fehler)

Comment: Sorry, I was a tad faster. But thanks for also thinking of this :)

Someone should merge these topics.

Comment: @fzwo But mine has pictures. ;-)

Comment: Yes, that's why I want yours merged to mine :p

J/k, I don't care whose question was here first, I'd just like to see this resolved before the end of Beta.