# Deutsche Anführungszeichen unterstützen

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Es ist sehr schwer, auch mit deutschen Tastaturen, normale deutsche Anführungszeichen einzugeben (zumindest kenne ich keinen besseren Weg als *Alt + 0132* `„` sowie *Alt + 0147* `“`). Sie sehen aber viel schöner aus.

Ist es lohnenswert, den Gebrauch dieser Zeichen auf dieser Seite zu unterstützen? Wäre es z.B. möglich, eine neue Taste im Fragen-Editor hinzuzufügen, die ein solches Anführungszeichenpaar einfügt (und wenn Text markiert ist, dann direkt darum)?

**English:**

It is quite hard, even with German keyboards, to insert German typographic quotation marks (the easiest way I know of is *Alt + 0132* `„` and *Alt + 0147* `“`). They look much better, however.

Is it desirable to support their use on this site? For example, would it be possible to add a new button to the question editor which inserts a pair of such quotation marks (and if some text is highlighted, around that)?

Comment: You should ask this kind of thing in English :-) (actually, the whole meta should be in English only)

Comment: @Stefano: +1 for requesting features in English, but I don't agree that the meta should be English only. That should be a meta post, actually.

Comment: Ich wage mal einzuwerfen, dass aus Sicht eines klassischen Schreibmaschinenbenutzers `"` durchaus aus normales Anführungszeichen empfunden wird. Das andere sind höhere ästhetische Ansprüche des Buchdrucks der möglicherweise durch die leichte Verfügbarkeit von Textverarbeitungsprogrammen in den Amateurbereich eingedrungen ist. Als Zyniker behaupte ich mal überspitzt, Textverarbeitungen sind Programme bei denen es im Gegensatz zu Texteditoren mehr auf die Form, als auf den Inhalt ankommt. Also zusammenfassend ein **nice to have feature**.

Comment: Tipp für Nutzer von OS X: `option` (`alt`) + `^` bzw. `option` + `2`. Aktuelle Linux-Desktopsysteme können es oft mit `alt gr` + `v` und `alt gr` + `b`. Wenn man sich einmal daran gewöhnt hat, läuft es ohne Probleme. Gedankenstrich, Ellipse und Apostroph haben natürlich auch ihre Entsprechungen.

Answer (score 3):

Ich habe nichts dagegen, und da ich nicht professionell mit Sprache arbeite - nicht in einem Umfeld, in dem man auf derartige Möglichkeiten Wert legen würde - will ich meine Laxheit in dieser Angelegenheit, nicht normativ für andere setzen.

Mir selbst ist es zu viel Arbeit; es hemmt meinen Schreibfluss, aber wenn es nur optional ist müsste ich mich ja nicht daran stören.

Platz für Buttons ist ja auch noch reichlich da.

#### english translation:

I'm not working in a context, where this distinction is important, but my own freedom should not hinder other people, to whom it is important. As an optional feature, it is welcome. Enogh room for buttons at the Textfield is available.

Comment: Ich habe nicht vor, irgendeine Regelung diesbezüglich durchzusetzen :) mein Vorschlag soll lediglich sein, die Benutzung auf der Seite so einfach wie möglich zu machen.

Comment: Ich habe es auch nicht so verstanden, sondern als Evaluierung des Meinungsbildes - wollen wir sowas, ja oder nein oder unentschieden. Das Unentschiedene könnte man unausgesprochen lassen, aber ich glaube es kann hilfreich sein eine Nichtposition zu erläutern. Sei es, dass sich Leute anschließen wollen, die sich wiederfinden, oder sei es, dass die Position Widerspruch erzeugt, und so andere Positionen schärft.

Comment: Dann stellt sich eigentlich die Frage, ob nicht gleich äöüßÄÖÜ auch als Button angeboten werden.

Comment: @bernd_k: Das wäre vielleicht gar nicht so übel. Ähnlich der Wikipedia (auch wenn dort natürlich sehr viel mehr Sonderzeichen angeboten werden).

Comment: Ich denke wir konzentrieren uns hier auf eine möglichst spezielle Lösung für Deutsch und Englisch, d.h. inklusive der Zeichen die in Fremdworten vorkommen, aber ohne Rücksicht darauf, was andere Sprachseiten, die hier auf A51 entstehen brauchen könnten.

Comment: @bernd Ja, aber das ist auch in Ordnung so, solange wir aushalten, dass unsere Wünsche nicht zwangsläufig erfüllt werden.

Answer (score 3):

Bevor das umgesetzt werden kann, muss erst Mal der Standardfont geändert werden, denn der aktuelle [stellt schließende deutsche Anführungszeichen falsch dar](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56/font-bug-main-site-font-renders-german-closing-quotation-marks-wrongly).

---

We need to switch to a different main font before this can be tackled, because the current font [displays closing german quotation marks wrongly](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56/font-bug-main-site-font-renders-german-closing-quotation-marks-wrongly).